# Automatically blend colours to a match

Tags: function-construction, color

I have a restricted palette *(hue values given below)*

```
palette = {cobaltviolet, pthaloblue, cyan, sapgreen, emerald, 
permenentgreen, rawsienna, yellowochre, magenta, vermillion, 
cadmiumred, cadmiumyellow, 
titaniumwhite} = {#/360, #2/100, #3/100} & @@@ {{328, 35, 
  32}, {233, 100, 27}, {212, 86, 62}, {130, 73, 44}, {180, 88, 
  60}, {152, 96, 46}, {30, 65, 52}, {42, 75, 78}, {352, 75, 
  76}, {5, 76, 55}, {10, 91, 78}, {58, 100, 100}, {0, 0, 100}};
```

that I am using to blend colours subtractively using `Blend` interpolation. Using the functions `cc` and `cwf` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/241941/9923), I can blend an approximation to a desired colour by eye using different colours like this:

[image]

```
Row[{With[{co = {cobaltviolet, titaniumwhite, sapgreen, yellowochre}},
cwf[Join[
 co, {{#/360, #2/100, #3/100} & @@ {19, 22, 66}, 
  cc@Blend[
    ColorConvert[Hue[#, #2, #3], "RGB"] & @@@ co, {20, 9, 1, 6}]}]]],
With[{co = {magenta, titaniumwhite, pthaloblue, cadmiumyellow}}, 
cwf[Join[
 co, {{#/360, #2/100, #3/100} & @@ {19, 22, 66}, 
  cc@Blend[
    ColorConvert[Hue[#, #2, #3], "RGB"] & @@@ co, {2, 4, 5, 2}]}]]]}]
```

I can then either blend the colour with the following ratios: `{{magenta, titaniumwhite, pthaloblue, cadmiumyellow} , {2, 4, 5, 2}}`, or `{{cobaltviolet, titaniumwhite, sapgreen, yellowochre} , {20, 9, 1, 6}}`

This is fairly time consuming though, and I was wondering whether it would be possible to automate the process?

Comment: Are you given the desired color in a certain form, by the way? Or would you like to be able to pick it interactively?

Comment: @thoimur I have the colour values already, so don't need to pick it interactivly. I realise some values won't be possible to mix, for example strongly saturated oranges, but as near as possible would be good.

Comment: ah, I see. And just to be sure, I take it you’re forced to blend in RGB, since `Blend` interpolates differently depending on the colorspace, right?

Comment: @thorimur yes, have to blend in RGB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the palette in RGB:

```
RGBpalette = (List @@ ColorConvert[Hue[##], "RGB"]) & @@@ palette
```

Get the convex hull in RGB, and pick only those colors on the boundary—we'll use these for interpolation:

```
region = ConvexHullRegion[RGBpalette]
generators = 
 Select[(List @@@ RGBpalette), 
  RegionMember[RegionBoundary@ConvexHullRegion[List @@@ RGBpalette], #] &]
```

Get the nearest color to a point `RGBpt` in RGB space by choosing the nearest point with `RegionNearest[regionmesh, RGBpt]`; for this we need `regionmesh = ConvexHullMesh[RGBpalette]`.

We'll then use linear programming to find a suitable combination of generators to produce this. The padding and extra 1's are to enforce the ratios sum to 1.

```
ratios[RGBpt : {_, _, _}] := 
 LinearProgramming[Table[1, {Length[generators]}], 
  ArrayPad[Transpose[generators], {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, 1.], {#, 0} & /@ 
   Append[RegionNearest[regionmesh, RGBpt], 1]]
```

If we want to reconstruct the color:

```
recreate[RGBpt : {_, _, _}] := Blend[RGBColor /@ generators, ratios[RGBpt]]
```

#### Code Block

```
RGBpalette = (List @@ ColorConvert[Hue[##], "RGB"]) & @@@ palette;

region = ConvexHullRegion[RGBpalette];

generators = 
 Select[(List @@@ RGBpalette), 
  RegionMember[RegionBoundary@ConvexHullRegion[List @@@ RGBpalette], #] &];

regionmesh = ConvexHullMesh[RGBpalette];

ratios[RGBpt : {_, _, _}] := 
 LinearProgramming[Table[1, {Length[generators]}], 
  ArrayPad[Transpose[generators], {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, 1.], {#, 0} & /@ 
   Append[RegionNearest[regionmesh, RGBpt], 1]]

recreate[RGBpt : {_, _, _}] := Blend[RGBColor /@ generators, ratios[RGBpt]]

(* Test: for a point in the hull, we recover that point: *)

List @@ recreate[{0.5, 0.6, 0.7}]

(* produces {0.5, 0.6, 0.7}. *)
```

#### Recreation

Here's how it recreates the `brightness = 1` hue circle:

[image: A somewhat darker hue circle, since the source colors are overall a bit darker]

It's a lot darker, but unfortunately we need to trade off something given that the generating colors don't include the whole colorspace under interpolation.

We could use different "nearest" colors, though, by potentially using something else instead of `RegionNearest[regionMesh, RGBpt]`. For example, we could intersect our mesh with the region of colors with brightness equal to `RGBpt`, and then take `RegionNearest` with respect to the intersected region—then the colors wouldn't appear darker, but they would appear completely desaturated at brightness 1. It just depends on the goal!

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> (RGBColor @@ recreate[List @@ ColorConvert[Hue[ArcTan[#1, #2]/(2 Pi), Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2], 1], "RGB"]] &), 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> False, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

Comment: great, thank you. A linear programming method is far smarter! I can get what I need with `li = Thread@
  Select[Thread@{ratios[{0.5, 0.6, 0.7}], 
     RGBColor /@ generators}, #[[1]] > 
     0 &]; Thread@{{"cobaltviolet", "pthaloblue", "cyan", "sapgreen", 
      "emerald", "permenentgreen", "rawsienna", "yellowochre", 
      "magenta", "vermillion", "cadmiumred", "cadmiumyellow", 
      "titaniumwhite"}[[#]] & /@ 
   Flatten[Position[RGBColor /@ RGBpalette, #] & /@ li[[2]]], li[[1]]}`

Comment: amazing, thank you!